# Error while deploying web application to Amazon elastic beanstalk

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Eclipse EE Juno edition. I created a dynamic web application which uses Amazon Simple DB and retirviing some values and showing to users.
i have installed the AWS kit for using Amazon services.

I have an account for simpleDB.

I tried to deploy it to AWS Elastic Beanstalk (through the plugin). It shows me to select the server. I selected it as  AW Beanstalk with TOmcat 6 (asia Pacific Tokyo).

After sometime it gives this error.

Unable to upload application to Amazon S3: User: arn:aws:iam::379007759147:user/SSSS is not authorized to perform: elasticbeanstalk:CreateStorageLocation
User: arn:aws:iam::379007759147:user/SSSS is not authorized to perform: elasticbeanstalk:CreateStorageLocation

I wish to upload the web application to AWS beanstalk and appreciate your help in achieving it.

Answer (score 19):

It worked for me with the following permissions

1. AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess - AWS Managed policy
2. AWSElasticBeanstalkService - AWS Managed policy
3. AWSCodeDeployRole - AWS Managed policy
4. AWSCodeDeployFullAccess - AWS Managed policy

Answer (score 8):

The user need to have 3 permissions:

- IAM(read)
- S3(write)
- Beanstalk(write)

and, there is a limitation of 1 user can maximum be attached with 2 policy.

so, maybe you need to create 3 groups and assign this user to these 3 groups.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to run beanstalk from an AWS **Lightsail** instance, which is forbidden apparently.

The role AmazonLightsailInstanceRole, pre-assigned to **Lightsail** server default user ("ec2-user" for aws linux), cannot be modified to include Elastic Beanstalk permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I think they change these often, some of the other answers' roles don't exist anymore .. in 2022 I had to enable AdministratorAccess-AWSElasticBeanstalk for it to work.

Answer (score -1):

Your IAM profile (i.e. the user you login with) hasn't been given the permissions required to create S3 buckets. Beanstalk creates a new bucket in which to dump application versions. Talk to whomever is root-administering your AWS account. They should be able to fix your IAM profile.

Comment: right, but what permission is required? I  have added elasticbeanstalk:CreateStorageLocation in the policy for a specific user on the specific application resource and i still get this error

Comment: @Mortimer Hmmmm... and the error is exactly the same (assuming the user you enfranchised)? In that case I'd email AWS support, but I'd strongly suspect it's something misconfigured in IAM, whether it's actually a different user, or a different region or the like.

Comment: following the example [from this AWS blog](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/03/resource-level-iam-for-elastic-beanstalk.html), it seems that I was doing things wrong as the `elasticbeanstalk:CreateStorageLocation` doesn't go on the beanstalk application policy, but on something else, which is still unclear to me. `*` seems to do the trick, even if it seems too permissive for my taste.

Comment: This error also occurs when your user has S3 permissions but not AWSElasticBeanstalk permissions

Comment: how about for the case that our web app doesn't use the aws s3 service?

Comment: @Timeless -- afraid I'm not an elasticbeastalk user these days and don't recall its behavior. Hopefully someone else will know!

Comment: @Christopher May I ask the reason you left elastic beanstalk?

Comment: @Timeless -- At the time (this was three years ago), beanstalk was a fairly un-fun product. It was basically a front for a couple of other AWS services with some tiny, semi-hidden scripts littered about the OS which handled some routing / wiring / alerting on init. Like most AWS products, it's just existing art from the world + a little intellectual property + API calls to their own stuff. It was difficult to manage, because you needed a toolchain to update AMIs. I moved companies and never went back, preferring to wire my own version of it with the EC2 API. It could be much better these days.

Comment: @Timeless -- here, for example, is Netflix's OSS product that does the same thing: https://github.com/Netflix/asgard. And some discussion about beanstalk vs asgard: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/asgardusers/SD4asJq9T9s